# What's the difference between a project and a workspace in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext

I think both are doing the **same!** When should I use a**workspace** and when a **project**, and what are the **differences**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Projects in Sublime are contained in `sublime-project` files, and allow you to:

- Control what folders are present in the project
- Per folder control of what files and folders from within are rejected from the project or included in the project
- Can contain settings that apply only to files open in that window
- Can contain build systems that apply only from within that window
- Persist the window layouts, open files, undo buffers, selected items in panels, and so on in an associated `sublime-workspace` file (or files; you can have more than one `sublime-workspace` associated with a particular project.

Workspaces in Sublime are are stored in `sublime-workspace` files, and:

- Contain anonymous project data as in a `sublime-project` file, except that your only access is to the list of folders open; the ability to control the contents of them or to use project specific settings and build systems is not present. This information is considered Anonymous because it's not persisted to disk, and is not editable (except in adding or removing folders using menu items)
- Persist the window layouts, Open files, undo buffers, selected items in panels, and so on.

A `sublime-project` always has one or more `sublime-workspace` files associated with it, whereas it is possible to have a `sublime-workspace` file that is not associated with a project if you desire.

Generally speaking, if you're working with source control (e.g. `git`), then you would include a `sublime-project` file in the repository but not a `sublime-workspace` file. This is because anything you do will modify the workspace file as well, making life painful when it comes to checking things in.

So, overall, the tradeoff between using Projects or just Workspaces revolves around what you're doing. If you're just opening folders and want to persist that window, but you don't have any need for the more advanced abilities that Projects provide, there's no reason to use them.

Comment: "This is because anything you do will modify the workspace file as well, making life painful when it comes to checking things in." <-- is this the main motivation for breaking project and workspace into 2 files? just curious why they didn't go with the approach of just one .sublime file that combines project and workspace info

Comment: Possibly; its not uncommon for tools of this sort to do something like this. I've seen quite a few cases where there are so many files that there needs to be an entire folder to contain them all instead of just a couple of files (which you can store anywhere you like).